# Removing index from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am new in MongoDB and did an import of DB to my local. I get the following error after running my node app.

`(node:1592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: exception: Index with name: expires_1 already exists with different options`

I logged in to the mongo console and got the following indexes for collection - Session

```
Indexes for sessions:
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "db_staging.sessions"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "expires" : 1
                },
                "name" : "expires_1",
                "ns" : "db_staging.sessions",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

And then I got another same index name under system.indexes

[image]

Can I remove the duplicate key from system.indexes.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your node code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ytkang/e3ac863f9e5ba3643d58becc8763cae3
use this tool for managing index

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all datas in indexes.
[image]